# php script will only run one at a time 

Tags: php

I have a script that I want to make sure only one is running, I am doing:

```
$fp = fopen("lock.txt", "w");
if (flock($fp, LOCK_EX|LOCK_NB)) { // do an exclusive lock
   //Processing code

   flock($fp, LOCK_UN);
}else{
   echo "Could not lock file!";
}

fclose($fp);
```

The problem is when I start the second script, it just stays there waiting. If I then stop the first script, the second script will then print "Could Not lock this file". Why doesn't the second script just stop immediately and report that message?

If it ran the second script, it would know that the file is locked and should exit. When I watch my processes I can see the second script sat there ... it's just wating.

Thanks.

EDIT: I have just tried a quick and dirty database lock i.e set a running field to -1 and check for it when the script opens. But that doesn't work. I have also tried using sockets as described: [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1861321/how-to-prevent-multiples-instances-of-a-script) . It seems like the second file won't even run ... Should I even be worried?

Comment: Are you running this on Windows by chance? According to the flock documentation, it looks like Windows doesn't support No Blocking flag.

Comment: No I am running it on a Linux VPS. I think it's running Centos although I cannot remember. Also, I think the issue is more to do with the fact the second script won't actually run a second time - In line with my edit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$fp = fopen("lock.txt", "w");
$block = 0;
if (flock($fp, LOCK_EX|LOCK_NB, $block)) { // do an exclusive lock
   sleep(5);
   flock($fp, LOCK_UN);
   echo "Could lock file!";
}else{
   echo "Could not lock file!";
}

fclose($fp);
```

works for me. Try adding the 3'rd parameter

---

Edit: 
You may have some session locking problems:
when you call session_start() it will block(put further requests in a waiting state) any other requests to your script until the original script that started the session has finished. To test this, try either accessing with 2 different browsers, or avoid calling session_start() in this script.

Comment: Does my original code work for you? (I will test this solution later when I get home). I am trying to see if there is a server setting that may be messing it up as all examples I have seen do it the way I am doing it.

Comment: Yes, it seems that the original code also works (after adding a `sleep` to be able to test it). You may have some session problems though. The accessing that page, do you use the same browser?

Comment: Yes I use the same browser. Question: If you set the sleep to something like 20 seconds and run the script, does the second really show the message at the same time? My first script will be running for a long time you see. THanks for your continued help!

Comment: Yeap. Thats how i define "it works":) I've said that you may have session problems, because when you call `session_start()` it will block(put them in a waiting state) any other requests to your script until the original script that started the session has finished. To test this, try either acessing with 2 different browsers, or avoid calling `session_start()` in this script.

Comment: That is a very good point! I didn't even think about the session start at the beginning! I don't actually use sessions on this script so don't need it! Can you add that to your main post please and I will mark an answer. Thanks!