# Show which file a php instance is running on server (for memory management purposes)

Tags: php, linux, cron

How can I check which file a current php instance is running?

I am on a VPS with shared resources and continue to hit my quota - yet I don't know where to start to investigate which php file is causing high memory issues

I would like to set up a cron job that runs a linux command or a php script that will tell me what the current state is of the php instance and what files are running and how much memory they are consuming

Comment: do you have access to ps?  `ps -ax | grep php`

Comment: If your PHP apps are running out of memory surely they're causing out of memory errors in the event log, could you check that first?

Comment: ps -ax states bad parameter

Comment: @scragar What type of logs are available for memory errors? I see a lot of http error log files, but not sure where memory logs are stored...

Comment: @morty346 Your PHP error log should contain the errors. It's `/var/log/php_error` on my CentOS VM, and in my XAMPP install it's `C:\xampp\php\php_error.log` - In general it's in the same directory as PHP itself or /var/log, but that can be changed in your PHP.ini file, so if it's not in a default location check the configuration of your server.

Comment: @scragar not seeing one... here is what I see http://pastebin.com/d7REzCp8 (this is in /var/log)

Comment: @Dave $ ps -ax
bash: $: command not found
$ Warning: bad ps syntax, perhaps a bogus '-'? See http://procps.sf.net/faq.html

Comment: Try searching your PHP.ini file for `error_log`, that will contain the path of your log file. `grep 'error_log' /etc/php.ini`

Comment: @scragar perhaps im blind - but I don't see it in there http://pastebin.com/3fqEtH3P

Comment: @Dave if I disregard the bad syntax warning - it only shows that php53.cgi is running it doesn't show me anything about which file

Comment: `ps-a` depending on your platform.  does it show one PHP instance or multiple?

Comment: @scragar I added log_errors = 1 and error_log = PATH to php.ini

Comment: @Dave 
$ ps -a doesn't show much of use - assuming you mean ps ax? then that shows multiple ps ax | grep php
11226 ?        S      0:00 php53.cgi
14030 pts/1    S+     0:00 grep php
23415 ?        S      0:05 php53.cgi

Comment: look at the answer (O votes) here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13836307/how-to-prevent-php-script-running-more-than-once

Comment: he said he isn't getting the script name in ps

Answer (score 1):

if the error logging that @scragar suggested doesn't give you fruit, you could have all your (suspect) php files dump their process id into the error log with `getmypid()` which will give you a timestamp to correlate with your cron job of `ps ax` allowing you to match up piggy processes gobbling up memory with the pid of the file

`error_log ( __FILE__.' pid='.getmypid());`

Comment: That makes sense - appreciate it will investigate after I get a bit of data in the logs