# Run the process only once using php and singleton

Tags: php, asynchronous, singleton

I am reading data from the sheet and want to implement singleton in my process so that I can run read function, one at a time.

I have written a code for the same which calls the class and set a static variable and then call the function to check if it has the class, so if the class is there then don't run the read function.

```
class DataParser extends config {

   private static $_instance = false;

   public static
   function getInstance() {
     if (self::$_instance == false) {
        print_r("expression");
        self::$_instance = true;
        return self::$_instance;

     }
     return false;
   }

   function __construct($params) {}
}

$dataParser = new DataParser($confData);
$p = DataParser::getInstance();
if ($p) {
 $res = $dataParser - > read();

}
```

I want to run the read function one at a time, if one read is running then the other read will not run.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to prevent multiples instances of a script?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1861321/how-to-prevent-multiples-instances-of-a-script)

Answer (score 0):

A singleton needs to prevent public constructing and cloning. This can simply be achieved by declaring these methods as `protected`.

To check if `read()` is currently being executed, you can use a flag `$isRunning`.

```php
<?php

class DataParser
{
    protected static $instance;

    protected static $isRunning = false;

    protected function __construct()
    {
    }

    protected function __clone()
    {
    }

    public static function getInstance(): DataParser
    {
        if (null === self::$instance) {
            self::$instance = new self();
        }

        return self::$instance;
    }

    public function read(): void
    {
        if (static::$isRunning) {
            throw new RuntimeException('DataParse is already running');
        }

        static::$isRunning = true;

        // Do some reading

        static::$isRunning = false;
    }
}
```

Comment: its not working as the way i want as i have only one instance. In php i have to hit the the url which will do all this work so after hitting the url it will always start the process for zero but i want it to check if there is already the process is going on or not @arueckauer

Comment: That's a total different question and has nothing to do with a singleton! Please do some search, there are already other similar questions with great solutions, e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1861321/how-to-prevent-multiples-instances-of-a-script